# Too many “Voting corrected” events

Tags: support, bug, serial-voting

I think the serial voting check algorithm is harassing me: I got ***six*** “Voting corrected” messages in my reputation tab in the last ***seven*** days.

This had no apparent effect on my overall rep, but it's very annoying to know that voting for my answers will be invalidated for obscure reasons.

I can't imagine what's happening, but I strongly suspect that every vote from a particular user is invalidated. Either if this is the case or not, I'd like to be informed about this and not only with vague justifications like “we cannot disclose details about the algorithm”. If my suspicion is correct I believe it is a bug in the algorithm, but at least the user should be notified.

---

Update. ***Seven*** events in eight days. Today, 13 May, nineteen votes have been invalidated. And the reputation page is telling lies, because my rep for 12 May was 230, not the ridiculously wrong 420 it reports.

[image]

---

Update (May 15). ***Eight*** events in ten days. This is becoming ***very*** annoying.

---

Update (November 25). After six months, no trace of an answer, even for saying “it's none of your business, we know what we're doing”.

Comment: What more notification do you want than the "Voting corrected" messages?

Comment: @PaulGessler I'm not talking about the message, but about *why* this happened six times in seven days.

Comment: @egreg: Don't answer any questions for a month... maybe more... so we have a control to work from. Sorry, this is a self-motivated suggestion. ;)

Comment: For what it's worth, the [420 has been corrected to show 230](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DFDoh.png).

Comment: [I've pinged the powers](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3440359#3440359)... maybe someone bites.

Comment: I am beginning to think **I** am the culprit of this serial voting reversal thingy. For testing purposes, I won't vote for two days; if nothing disturbs the votes, it's an evidence I am breaking the voting algorithm. Sorry.